# ionic 4 ion-grid not going to centered/

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am tring to show my grid centered on screen but it showing on right side

Here is my code

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">

<h3 style="margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 30px;">Home</h3>


<div>
<ion-grid style="height: 100%">
  <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center">
    <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let x of data">
      <ion-card class="card-img" (click)="detail()">
          <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" style="height: 180px; width: 150px;">
          <div style="text-align: center;" class="boxe">
          <ion-icon name="checkmark" class="tick" color="medium"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="close" class="cross" color="dark"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </ion-card>

    </ion-col>


    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

.scss

```
.card-img{
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

.tick{

    text-align:center;
   font-size: 30px;

}
.cross{

    text-align:center;
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

As in image in need to centered the grid and remove top spaces between images

[image]

Comment: check edited answer bro.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This : -**

**page.scss**

```
.card-img{
   border-radius: 10px;

    img{
      width: 100%;
    }
 }
```

Comment: i remove padding from ion-content and add you updated code still not showing the grid in center

Comment: see the image i am putting my answer, its center

Comment: yes its working but i need to add width in card because image width is less then from card width. when i add with in card-img class its not remain in centered

Comment: add my scss also . i  fit the widht of image in card .

Comment: bro, try remove the card width and give width 100% in image then check your output.